# const char* to double

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I'm trying to use an if statement to check when the time goes past a specific point and run a specific function. To do this I'm looking to convert time into a double and running something along the lines of `if(timeCurrent >= 8.30)`. I seem to however have an issue with the conversion part, normally I'm aware the standard practice in C++ would be to do the following:

```
DateTime now = rtc.now();
static char buffer[80];

sprintf(buffer, "%02d.%02d", now.hour(), now.minute());
String str(buffer);
double timeCurrent = strtod(str);
```

However, this doesn't work for Arduino. What can be done to create the same desired function?

Comment: this may help ... you made no mention of any research that you may have done ... https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time

Comment: convert buffer to float, not String. but there are more elegant end efficient solutions. if you really want float then `0.01 * m + h`

Comment: There is really no need to take the extra effort in converting first to char buffer, then String and then double. Just convert the ints from the RTC directly to a float like juraj wrote. And I doubt, that your code is a good practice in C++ either

Comment: `I'm aware the standard practice in C++ would be to do the following`... Umm... no, it certainly would *not*. What would give you that impression?

Answer (score 3):

Don't do that. Converting a time to `double` is highly inefficient.
Moreover, your approach suffers from a rollover issue every 24h.

If you just want to compare the time of day with 8:30, you can do it in
a very straightforward way:

```
if (now.hour() > 8 || (now.hour() == 8 && now.minute() >= 30))
```

If the long `if` annoys you, you can put the comparison logic inside a
`static inline` function. If you really want to combine hour and minute
into a single number, then convert to an integer rather than a double:

```
if (now.hour() * 100 + now.minute() >= 830)
```

This can be made more efficient if you think in binary rather than
decimal: you can build a 16-bit number with one byte holding the hours
and the other byte holding the minutes:

```
if ((now.hour() << 8) | now.minute() >= (8 << 8) | 30)
```

Again, you may encapsulate the `((a)<<8|(b))` in a macro or static
inline function if it helps with readability. If you want to compare to
an absolute time, your best option is to build a `DateTime` object
representing the deadline, and compare with `now` as:

```
// Assume timeout should be today at 8:30.
DateTime timeout(now.year(), now.month(), now.day(), 8, 30, 0);
if (now.secondstime() >= timeout.secondstime())
```

Here the `secondstime()` method is used to convert the `DateTime` into a
scalar number (a 32-bit integer of type `time_t`) that can be easily
compared and is far more efficient than using floats.